# How to remove colon in resumeItemListStart

Tags: remove

I want to know how can I remove colon that appears after the "Discussion Forum Upgrades" in the code below:

```
\resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Discussion Forum Upgrades}
          {Refactor forum for performance to handle large databases.}
      \resumeItemListEnd
```

This is how the result looks like:
[image]

Also, here is the source code:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/resume-template-by-anubhav/dhmkrwtksdgy

Please note that I prefer not to use \itemize command as it changes the spacing in my document.

Comment: Welcome. // The colon is produced by the macro \resumeItem{ }. To remove it, just remove the colon there OR copy that macros content into \renew\resumeItem{ ... }, where you delete the colon, OR define your own macro and use it instead of \resumeItem.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MS-SPO. I am using overleaf, so I think it is not possible to remove the colon from macro. Can you please let me know how can I create my own macro or create a new macro in overleaf?

Comment: May be a good start is reading the section about macros, which also talks about the renew-command (overwriting an existing macro with the same name) at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros . You see some code examples there. Also have a look at the template you mentioned pressing "View Source". // All you'd need to do is to copy from the template, put a "re" infront of it and delete the ":" ... before you start \begin{document}

Comment: BTW, what you'd do is: 1) creating a new file with \documentclass, \begin{document} + \end{document}; 2) put \usepackage{nameOfTheCvTemplate}; 3) use macros as predefined in the template AND explained in its documentation. // If you haven't done so far, start with simpler .tex trials (printing hello world etc.) before moving to the CV. Move "hello world" into your own macro and just call the macro instead. And so on. This way you'll get more familiar with Latex.